# ReCaptchaV3 - does not work for some users

Tags: recaptcha-v3

Recently installed recaptcha v3. Over 1 million calls per day.

Periodically, for some users, it shows the following error:

> "grecaptcha.execute('" crashes by timeout. > 10 seconds

The cache update helps. Cannot reproduce the problem locally.

How can I diagnose problem? What events can be logged?